# How can I pass parameters to the bit.ly api using python?

Tags: python, api, bit.ly

I'm trying to pass in some parameters to the link_clicks and link_countries bit.ly APIs with python however I'm not sure of the syntax to pass the parameters here. How can I add parameters to this api call?

```
import sys
import bitly_api
import os
from config import config


#connect to bitly
conn_btly = bitly_api.Connection(access_token=config['ACCESS_TOKEN'])

#get links
links = conn_btly.user_link_history()

print 'links okay'


for link in links:

    #add params to link
    link_full = link['link'] + '?rollup=false'
    print link_full

    #get clicks
    clicks = conn_btly.link_clicks(link_full)

    #print results
    #print link['link'], clicks
    print clicks
```

the resulting output is

```
links okay
http://mzl.la/19xSyCT?rollup=false
...
BitlyError: NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass in `rollup` as a keyword parameter instead:

```
clicks = conn_btly.link_clicks(link['link'], rollup=False)
```

You are expected to pass in a Python boolean value. The parameter is not part of the bit.ly URL, it is a parameter to the API call instead.

All optional API parameters (so apart from the link), are passed in as keyword parameters, including `unit`, `units`, `tz_offset` and `limit`.

You can take a look at the [internal method that handles these parameters](https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python/blob/master/bitly_api/bitly_api.py#L702) if you are so inclined.

Comment: Taking this a step further, I'm trying to filter my link_countries results to a specific date using the `unit_reference_ts` like so: `countries = conn_btly.link_countries(link['link'], rollup=False, unit="day", unit_reference_ts=click['dt'])` but it looks like this is an invalid parameter. Am I calling it incorrectly?

Comment: `unit_reference_ts` is not supported by the Python API, it looks like.

Comment: You could try to call the `_call_oauth2_metrics` method directly: `conn_btly._call_oauth2_metrics("v3/link/countries", {'link': link['link'], 'unit_reference_ts': click['dt']}, rollup=False, unit='day')`. E.g. add any additional parameters that are not explicitly supported into the `params` dictionary. No idea if that'll work, YMMV.